# How to Pass Inherited Widgets to Entire Material App

Tags: flutter

So i have an inherited widget that looks like :

```
class InheritedStateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;

  InheritedStateWidget({
    @required this.child
  });

  @override
  InheritedStateWidgetState createState() => new InheritedStateWidgetState();

  static of(BuildContext context) {
    return (context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_MyInheritedWidget) as _MyInheritedWidget).data;
  }
}

class InheritedStateWidgetState extends State<InheritedStateWidget> {
  String _userName;

  // Getter methods
  String get tasks => _userName;

  void changeUserName(String name) {
    setState(() {
      _userName = name;      
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _MyInheritedWidget(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

}

class _MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final InheritedStateWidgetState data;

  _MyInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.data,
    Widget child}): super(key: key, child: child);

    @override
    bool updateShouldNotify(_MyInheritedWidget old) {
      return true;
    }
}
```

And a main.dart like this:

```
void main() => runApp(InheritedStateWidget(
  child: new Builder ( builder: (context) => new MyApp()))
  );

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App One',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

  int currentTab;
  Widget currentPage;
  List<Widget> pages;
  HomePage one;
  ProfilePage two;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    one = HomePage(
      key: exploreKey,
    );
    two = Profile(
      key: myTasksKey,
    );

    pages = [one, two];

    currentPage = one;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Testing"),),
      body: new PageStorage(
        bucket: bucket,
        child: currentPage,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: currentTab,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentTab = index;
            currentPage = pages[index];
          });
        },
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem> [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Home"),
            icon: null
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            title: Text("Profile"),
            icon: null
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

From what i've gotten from some guides this is how i should pass Inherited Widgets to my Material App and all its routes but it doesn't seem to be passing the Inherited Widget Past the Scaffold. From the Scaffold itself it seems like i'm able to do something like :

> InheritedStateWidget.of(context)

And it would successfully bring back my Inherited widget but while in the currentPage Widget i.e HomePage(Stateful Widget). I can't seem to access it and i get

> Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'HomePageState' has
>   no instance getter 'InheritedStateWidget'. Receiver: Instance of
>   'HomePageState'

Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I restructured your top few classes slightly:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(InheritedStateWidget());

class InheritedStateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  InheritedStateWidgetState createState() => InheritedStateWidgetState();
}

class InheritedStateWidgetState extends State<InheritedStateWidget> {
  String _userName;

  // Getter methods
  String get tasks => _userName;

  void changeUserName(String name) {
    setState(() {
      _userName = name;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MyInheritedWidget(
      data: this,
      child: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  final InheritedStateWidgetState data;

  MyInheritedWidget({Key key, this.data, Widget child})
      : super(key: key, child: child);

  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(MyInheritedWidget);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInheritedWidget old) => true;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // in MyApp and below you can refer to MyInheritedWidget.of(context).data
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'App One',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

I prefer to strengthen the interface between the State and the InheritedWidget like this, but just a suggestion...

```
void main() => runApp(new Controller());

class Controller extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ControllerState();
}

typedef void VoidIntFunction(int i);

class ControllerState extends State<Controller> {
  String someString = '';

  void someFunction(int v) {
    print('function called with $v');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StateContainer(
      someString: someString,
      someFunction: someFunction,
      child: new ExampleApp(),
    );
  }
}

class StateContainer extends InheritedWidget {
  final String someString;
  final VoidIntFunction someFunction;

  const StateContainer({
    this.someString,
    this.someFunction,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  static StateContainer of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(StateContainer);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(StateContainer oldWidget) => true;
}
```

Any child now using the InheritedWidget just has read access to the state (`someString`) and has to modify it by calling methods (`someFunction`). There's a bit more boilerplate involved.

Comment: Seems to be giving me this error `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.`

Comment: Seems it was something on my side. Works now.