# Is there a way to use an InheritedWidget in multiple PageRoutes in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have an `InheritedWidget` at the root of my application, basically at the top of the first build function of my first `Scaffold`. I can reference the widget using the `.of(context)` function just fine from all sub-widgets of the first page. if I push another page on the `Navigator` stack, the `InheritedWidget.of()` call fails, as I assume it should. Is there a way to share access to this widget? I'm trying to avoid passing widgets down the tree unnecessarily. ScopedModel has the same limitation. I was thinking about passing the context variable down the tree, but that doesn't sound right and it doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass Inherited Widgets to Entire Material App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441536/how-to-pass-inherited-widgets-to-entire-material-app)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Pass Inherited Widgets to Entire Material App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441536/how-to-pass-inherited-widgets-to-entire-material-app)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should wrap your root widget with it, for example your `MaterialApp`

```
MyInheritedWidget(
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: home))
```

Comment: It should give me the same results, since all widgets are called from under this main scaffold.It's the first widget I return

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! It didn't work last time I tried it, but maybe something was different, thank you.

Comment: When you wrap your material app with it , it will allow access to the inherited widget from the navigator stack, so it will solve your problem